# Two Alert Views in One View Controller - buttonIndex Response

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I am trying to perform the smile task of having two alerts in a single View Controller. The code below works fine, but how would I make another instance of it elsewhere in the View Controller. I am concerned that if I duplicated the code, my buttonIndex would not know which alert it is responding to. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
-(void)alertChoice
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"
    message:@"Message" delegate:self
    cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Confirm", nil];
    [alert show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1) 
    {
    //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the `tag` property on `UIAlertView` to decipher which alert is which:

```
-(void)alertChoice
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"
    message:@"Message" delegate:self
    cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Confirm", nil];
    alert.tag = 0;
    [alert show];
}

-(void)alertChoice1
{
    UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"
    message:@"Message" delegate:self
    cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Confirm", nil];
    alert1.tag = 1;
    [alert1 show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(alertView.tag == 0)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply set a tag to each Alert view and check which one sent the messeg.

```
alertView.tag=0;
```

And then

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

if(alertView.tag==0){

      if(buttonIndex == 0)//OK button pressed
     {
       //do something
     }
     else if(buttonIndex == 1)//Annul button pressed.
     {
      //do something
     }
}else{

  if(buttonIndex == 0)//OK button pressed

       {
        //do something
      }
      else if(buttonIndex == 1)//Annul button pressed.
    {
    //do something
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

set tag to alert view.

```
alert.tag = 1;

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1 && alertView.tag == 1) 
    {
    //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Add **UIAlertViewDelegate** in your view controller.h file

step 2: Add the following methods in your view controller.m file

```
-(void)AlertMethodOne
{
  UIAlertView *alertview=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"AlertMethodOne" message:@"AlertMethodOne successfully Called" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    alert.tag=101;
    [alertview show];  
}

-(void)AletrMethodTwo
{
UIAlertView *alertview=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"AletrMethodTwo" message:@"AlertMethodTwo successfully Called" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
alert.tag=102;
    [alertview show]; 
}
```

call the above two methods in your viewController as like below:
   [self AlertMethodOne];
   [self AlertMethodTwo];

Now AlertView Button Clicked Method

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if(alertView.tag==101)
{
   if (buttonIndex == 0)
   {
   }
}
if(alertView.tag==102)
{
   if (buttonIndex == 1)
   {  
   }
}
}
```